# Batch file loop through a directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder in a directory that contains 500 .exe files. At the moment, I use this code to go through the directory and run the .exe files:

```
echo file.exe
echo file.exe >>%LOGFILE%
&PATH&\file.exe /quiet /norestart
```

This is currently repeated 500 times with each file name.

I've had a look around online and found this: `for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i`

So would this work? Or is there a better way?

```
for /r %%i in (*) do 
echo file.exe
echo file.exe >>%LOGFILE%
&PATH&\file.exe /quiet /norestart 
%%i
```

Could someone elaborate/explain? :)

Comment: Will it work: you need parentheses around the loop body, but otherwise: you need to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is a bit off in some places, but yes, that should work sort-of:

```
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do (
  echo %%~nxi
  echo %%~nxi>>%LOGFILE%
  "%%i" /quiet /norestart 
)
```

`%%~nxi` contains the name and extension of the current file in the loop